# Redirecting to a route from withing a private function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a private function with a `try..catch` block which is supposed to redirect to a generic error page in the `catch` block. The problem is that because the function returns a ViewModel type if I do `Return RedirectToRoute()` there is a conversion error. Is there a way from within this function to redirect to a route so I can display the error page if the catch block fires?

Answer (score 0):

If your function is an action result then you can redirect to another actionresult or another controller for example;

```
public ActionResult asdf()
{
    . . .

    // return View(model); normally

    return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction");

    OR

    return Redirect("/ControllerName/ActionName?QueryParameter=Value");

    OR

   string samplecontent = "<h1>For example</h1>";
   return Content(samplecontent);

}
```

Comment: The function returns a view model not an action results so that does not work.

Comment: Normal ! ActionResult can have a View. But if you want, you can redirect to another action result or you can send a content with `return Content(StringValue);`

Comment: It need to return the model so things calling to the function can fill variables with the results. I do not want to return an ActionResult